# GoPro Camera Live Stream with IIS7

Tags: iis-7, video-streaming

Has anyone here successfully been able to setup a GoPro camera to stream through IIS7 Live Smooth Streaming service?

Would a GoPro camera be ideal for live streaming or do you guys have any other suggestions for a better alternative. Of course it needs to be compatible with IIS.

Thank you for taking time to read this.